# Leer un XML desde HTML y aplicarlos directamente en la vista

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Estoy intentando cargar un XML a una vista y que con JS me lo lea y los tag los use directamente en varios inputs que existen en esa misma visto, y todo lo deseo hacer desde el cliente. Si alguien ma puede ayudar.

Es un formulario que se debe llenar en base a un XML

---

En el HTML tengo un input normal y un div donde poner la informacion de adentro a manera de pruebas

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<div id="contenido-archivo"></div>
```

---

En el JS tengo lo siguiente para leerlo y colocarlo directamente en un div y funciona para agarrar todo el contenido del XML y mostrarlo en el DIV, pero quiero agarrar cada etiqueta del XML y usarla en otros inputs que existen en el formulario

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function leerArchivo(e) {
  var archivo = e.target.files[0];
  if (!archivo) {
    return;
  }
  var lector = new FileReader();
  lector.onload = function (e) {
    var contenido = e.target.result;
    mostrarContenido(contenido);
  };
  lector.readAsText(archivo);
}
function mostrarContenido(contenido) {
  var elemento = document.getElementById('contenido-archivo');
  elemento.innerHTML = contenido;
}
document.getElementById('file-input')
  .addEventListener('change', leerArchivo, false);
</script>
```

---

Parte del XML es esto

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<factura xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" id="comprobante" version="2.1.0">
<infoTributaria>
<codDoc>01</codDoc>
</infoTributaria>
</factura>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código de como lo estas haciendo ?

Comment: Hola Luis, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: @LucianoMontañez Ya actualice agregando información mas detallada